# Azure: Error thrown when following official doc to set up inbound policies for APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I followed steps on this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-protect-backend-frontend-azure-ad-b2c#set-up-the-cors-and-validate-jwt-policies) precisely, but got this error when saving the policy editor Under "Inbound processing" and code view button "</>":

```
One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Error in element 'cors' on line 2, column 5: Policy section is not allowed in the specified scope
Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 16, column 5: Policy section is not allowed in the specified scope
Error in element 'rate-limit-by-key' on line 24, column 5: Policy section is not allowed in the specified scope
```

here is the code:

```
<inbound>
   <cors allow-credentials="true">
         <allowed-origins>
             <origin>https://devjohn1.z11.web.core.windows.net/</origin>
         </allowed-origins>
         <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="120">
             <method>GET</method>
         </allowed-methods>
         <allowed-headers>
             <header>*</header>
         </allowed-headers>
         <expose-headers>
             <header>*</header>
         </expose-headers>
   </cors>
   <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." require-expiration-time="true" require-signed-tokens="true" clock-skew="300">
      <openid-config url="https://devjohn1.b2clogin.com/devjohn1.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_myapp_frontend_devjohn1_signupandsignin" />
      <required-claims>
         <claim name="aud">
            <value>56f39849-19eb-49d6-qweqw-123123123</value>
         </claim>
      </required-claims>
   </validate-jwt>
   <rate-limit-by-key calls="300" renewal-period="120" counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)" />
   <rate-limit-by-key calls="15" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
</inbound>
```

What can be wrong?  I was just following the steps....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have tried to reproduce the issue at my environment and got the same error as below**-

> One or more fields contain incorrect values:
>
> - Error in element 'cors' on line 2, column 10: Policy section is not allowed in the specified scope
> - Error in element 'validate-jwt' on line 16, column 10: Policy section is not allowed in the specified scope
> - Error in element 'rate-limit-by-key' on line 24, column 10: Policy section is not allowed in the specified scope

Whenever you will try to save the policies in the following manner, you will be get the error

[image]

After creating the new API in APIM click on the inbound policy code editor

[image]

After clicking, you will get the default policy template. Paste your inbound policies within `<inbound></inbound>` keeping other tags as is.

[image]

After few modification in your existing policy, I am able to save it. Keep `<inbound></inbound>` within `<policies></policies>`.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>https://devjohn1.z11.web.core.windows.net/</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="120">
                <method>GET</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." require-expiration-time="true" require-signed-tokens="true" clock-skew="300">
            <openid-config url="https://devjohn1.b2clogin.com/devjohn1.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_myapp_frontend_devjohn1_signupandsignin" />
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud">
                    <value>56f39849-19eb-49d6-qweqw-123123123</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
        <rate-limit-by-key calls="300" renewal-period="120" counter-key="@(context.Request.IpAddress)" />
        <rate-limit-by-key calls="15" renewal-period="60" counter-key="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","").AsJwt()?.Subject)" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Thank you!  you saved my day! I can't believe I got stuck in such a silly thing